# Mod_Rewrite Simplest Way to Hide Folder in URL For ALL Sub-directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got all my code for my website stored in my document root at `mywebfolder`. There are many sub-directories, e.g. `mywebfolder/deals/..` `mywebfolder/user/..` and so on. I'm currently hosting my site with mydomain.com.

I would like to not display `mywebfolder` at anytime, as it's redundant and makes my URLs unecessary longer and hard to remember. I've got a mod_rewrite running that accomplishes this, but only when i go to mydomain.com. (I.e. it only works for the document root). In my 000-default.conf file I've got the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Content"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebfolder/
            RewriteRule(.*) /mywebfolder/$1
    </Directory>
```

I understand that my conditions only do the rewrite when I navigate to mydomain.com. Is there anyway I can easily extrapolate these to the entire site so when navigating a user never sees `/mywebfolder/` in the URL? Or do I have to create a directory block for EVERY directory?

Comment: Your .conf seems fine and it is unclear what is not working as expected. Can you give the example full URL?

Comment: @DusanBajic This only works for when I first go to my domain. So I navigate to www.mydomain.com` and it goes to my splash page, which is at the directory mydomain.com/mywebfolder/, and displays properly without showing mywebfolder in the URL. However, as soon as I click any links and go into a deeper subfolder, mywebfolder displays. So for example I click a link from my splash page and it takes me to mydomain.com/mywebfolder/subdirectory/mypage.php. But I would like it to display: mydomain.com/subdirectory/mypage.php. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I see it now. It is possible but let me test it first.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule /mywebfolder/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebfolder/
RewriteRule /(.*) /mywebfolder/$1
```

Comment: This actually ended up leading me to my solution.. you are correct in saying that my original rewrite worked, although this is a better catch all solution. My issue is that all of the symbolic links on the website used the /mywebfolder/, so it was appearing in the bar. If I navigated directly to a link it would work. So I update all of my relative links and it seems to be functioning now. Thanks for your help!